# Axios Vue.js Pass an array of objects from store.js to component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-router

I am struggling with the Vue.js so i would like your help.

I want to do something too simple but unfortunately without luck. In the store.js i have an axios fetch that return the data from the called API.
My next step is to pass the object in the component.

I succeed to do it using  this.$store.dispatch('loadBeers') and mutation and i can rendered the items in my html.

BUT what if i want to handle the data in the helloworld component for instance to make a pagination and to filter the obj? My logic say to me that i need to store the obj in a new array and after i can handle my data.

How can i transfer this.myBeers to the helloworld component? 
Maybe my logic or my approach is not correct, so please forgive me i have experience just with the instance but the entire frame work is an other world...

Sorry for my terrible english i try to improve them every day. thanks in advance community..

Store.js

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";
import VueAxios from "vue-axios";

Vue.use(Vuex);
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    beers: []
  },
  data(){
    return{
      myBeers:[],
    }
  },
  actions: {
    loadBeers({ commit }) {
      axios
        .get("https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers")
        .then(r => {
          this.myBeers = r.data;
          console.log(this.beers);
          
      })
        .then(beers => {
          commit("SET_BEERS", beers);
        });
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_BEERS(state, beers) {
      state.beers = beers;
    }
  }
});
```

```js
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="beer in beers" :key="beer.id">
          <td>{{ beer.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ beer.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ beer.abv }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data(){
  return{
    myBeers:[],
  }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.$store.dispatch('loadBeers')
    this.myBeers=this.$store.dispatch('loadBeers')
  },
  computed: mapState([
    'beers'
  ]),
  methods:{

    test(){
     console.log(this.loadBeers);
    }
  }
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to filter based on the existing beer list you can use a getter. If you are using pagination you would need to add to `state.beers` not replace it. https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html In the component you can view the getter with `...mapGetters(['myBeer'])`

Or you could filter the beers in the action and add it to `state.filteredBeers`

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";
import VueAxios from "vue-axios";

Vue.use(Vuex);
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    beers: [],
    filteredBeers: []
  },

  getters: {
    myBeers(state){
       return.state.beers.filter(beer => beer)
    }
  },
  actions: {
    loadBeers({ commit }) {
      axios
        .get("https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers")
        .then(r => {
          commit("SET_BEERS", r.data);
          let filtered = r.data.filter(beer => beer.ipa)
          commit("SET_FILTERED", filtered)
      })
  
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_BEERS(state, beers) {
      state.beers = beers;
    },
    SET_FILTERED(state, filtered) {
      state.filteredBeers = filtered;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you always fetch all the data from the server and then do the filtering/pagination on the client-side, you can use computed properties inside your component

```js
<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data(){
  return{
    filter: 'test',
    curPage: 1,
    pageSize: 10,
  }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.$store.dispatch('loadBeers')
  },
  computed: {
  ...mapState([
    'beers'
  ]),
      filteredBeers()
      {
        const flt = this.filter.toLowerCase();
        return flt ? this.beers.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(flt) !== -1) : this.beers;
      },
      paginatedBeers()
      {
        return this.filteredBeers.slice((this.curPage - 1) * this.pageSize, (this.curPage - 1) * this.pageSize + this.pageSize - 1);
      } 
  },
  methods:{

    test(){
     console.log(this.paginatedBeers);
    }
  }
}


</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="beer in paginatedBeers" :key="beer.id">
          <td>{{ beer.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ beer.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ beer.abv }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: @Igo thank you a lot for your time but your answer created to me more questions. First of all i get an error that this.beers is undefined and here is my issue i can understand how you filter the data but i think that this.beers is an empty array.. this.beers referred to mapstate??

Comment: Would you like to provide a JSfiddle or CodePen ?

Comment: Yes for sure! I have never use it before so i cannot promise you anything but i will try..